# How to enforce type in complex object depending on siblings types

Tags: typescript

I'm looking for building a options type with internal constraints
I want the user to define some ways to authenticate caller
Then on each route the user can define if each can of caller can or not access this route (Guard).

I want to prevent user to define Guard for not defined authentication kinds
And give to the guard the context return by the authentication method as parameter

Here an example

```
type Options = {
  auths: {
    [key: string]: (req) => ? | null;
  }
  routes: [
    {
      guard: {
        [?]: boolean | ((ctxt: ?) => boolean);
      }
    }
  ]
}

const options: Options = {
  auths: {
    CUSTOMER: (req): Customer => {
      if (!isCustomer()) {
        throw new Error('Not a customer');
      }
      return { name: req.body.name };
    },
    COLLABORATOR: (req): Collaborator => {
      if (!isCollaborator()) {
        throw new Error('Not a collaborator');
      }
      return { ldap: req.body.ldap };
    },
  },
  routes: [ {
    guard: {
      CUSTOMER: false,
      COLLABORATOR: (collaborator: Collaborator) => isDevelopper(collaborator),
      SERVICE: false, // Should trigger a type error
    }
  } ]
}
```

This exemple refuse all customer and all collaborator which is not developper

Thanks for you helps

I found a first solution

```js
type Options<T extends Record<string,  unknown>> = {
  auths: {
    [Property in keyof T]: (req: Request) => T[Property];
  };
  routes: [
    {
      guard: {
        [Property in keyof T]?: boolean | ((ctxt: T[Property]) => boolean);
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there any way to not force user to define generic with types ?

```
type Context = {
  CUSTOMER: Customer;
  COLLABORATOR: Collaborator;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you would be fine with your described solution, provided that there would be a way to not have to explicitly specify the `T` (here `Context`) generic type?

Automatic inference of generic types occurs only for function/constructor arguments.

A classic workaround is therefore to use a "transparent" function with no other functionality than being used for this automatic inference:

```
// "Transparent" function, used only for automatic inference of generic type
function inferOptionsContext<T extends Record<string,  unknown>>(options: Options<T>) {
  return options;
}

inferOptionsContext({
  auths: { // Error: Property 'SERVICE' is missing in type '{ CUSTOMER: (req: Request) => Customer; COLLABORATOR: (req: Request) => Collaborator; }' but required in type '{ CUSTOMER: (req: Request) => unknown; COLLABORATOR: (req: Request) => Collaborator; SERVICE: (req: Request) => unknown; }'.
    CUSTOMER: (req): Customer => {
      if (!isCustomer()) {
        throw new Error('Not a customer');
      }
      return { name: req.body?.name };
    },
    COLLABORATOR: (req): Collaborator => {
      if (!isCollaborator()) {
        throw new Error('Not a collaborator');
      }
      return { ldap: req.body?.ldap };
    },
  },
  routes: [ {
    guard: {
      CUSTOMER: false,
      COLLABORATOR: (collaborator: Collaborator) => isDevelopper(collaborator),
      SERVICE: false, // Should trigger a type error // Actually the error is triggered on auths
    }
  } ]
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAFwngDgpgBA8hEBLA9gOwM4wLwwN7AwwCGAriABYYBc+hRMA2gNZRi0YgBOSaA5gF1aACi5QAjgEocAPhgB+AD4w0pADZqA3PQC+9LinJQaTekQIMGfUsS4ATWhcsMWMXjFZgUAM3iJUmIwA5GSUGEECQjAARigoalDEaDDKwsIAxiAAHiC08tLYcrHxiWiS2s4wepbVMALAeqCQsADCpJwoALZQXDj4KsTdHNy8fFVN0DAt8WrEsVzEICi9uHgwanbEEMM8-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-7DZ9JXOD9IP-XOa6Lsu4NgJDbMw7GT5bruhh+QeR42GFxNEFtLU3neD5w5LCNvv1+YZLTGNcGjBOATKIEYliOJ4qrQ3q7BbYIUKKFoRhsvYXhBFEeodikTw5GUW97GCU9XD0a6lXACxLEknbABE3ILJgEBfEtwenAi1IKe0UBO+gaixd4mOhF0ixIOkJneD0InpLA5kUd2PC5+xwA-IiyS8PnXCceSi3LfxgnCaJ4mSfYMkjPwCmKWgymqepwhTeSs30nx3IyNdzOzpSc2YA0JJ1z0jeYM3QkgMITjrf0dsUxrMC5UZsVBOblsCkE1wwJ0yIYKMcUe0EaxS9eooSLZEgOZwzmqvcmh4Y9SVh+FGNkYB2R-k5GU+MAKdSqNfaI5AQb2SQGIJ27hn6v0vNLD+4DIGOWckpFSuo0CAO6q+PqoDrJf3soQmBatyyAIvqhdCYDaFQKIYPEhZCEFBkTDg9+YD9p3EokdbGp08YfSJtjIgpMHq9i9gOKmw4PpfVKtOP689fT+kDKDFckMga81dHDChiNlZ4OLIw5sWM2ySJVNYsEV0Jbtjup2BRh9lFDjelBOB6jGaaJZv0NmejxBgwhkGHm3lNz8yfL5fyTBiahVPNjN+O1MJyzbGYkByMjbo3LJrOBzldZgQNpBRxXBTaVBYVbU4NsFJ20IsRJ2ZEKK9HdtVWimM7ZpkyDYDQsVKCwC6b0ZEzskCu3QZSZI2kfZVDqA0SQwAgA)